# Associations between models to render collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Action Cable chat program that has four basic models: `User`, `Chatroom`, `Message`, `Connect`.

These are the associations for `User`:

```
has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
has_many :chatrooms, through: :messages
has_many :connects, dependent: :destroy
```

These are the associations for `Chatroom`:

```
has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :messages
has_many :connects, dependent: :destroy
```

These are the associations for `Message`:

```
belongs_to :chatroom
belongs_to :user
```

These are the associations for `Connect`:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :chatroom
```

In the Show view for the Chatrooms there is a collection rendered:

```
<%= render partial: 'messages/message', collection: @chatroom.messages %>
```

This is what's inside the message partial that is rendered:

```
<p><strong><%=message.user.username%></strong>:  <%=message.content%></p>
```

Now I want to render an attribite value from `Connect` from the `current_user` in the current chat room into the same partial. I want something like this:

```
<p><strong><%=message.user.username%></strong>(<span class="agree"><%= current_user.connect.value%></span>):  <%=message.content%></p>
```

I tried to add another collection to the render command, but discovered RoR doesn't like that. I added a render into the message partial like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'partials/current', collection: @chatroom.users %>
```

This is rendering this partial:

```
(<span class="agree"><%= current.current_user.connect.value %></span>)
```

I think this can work. However, I'm getting stuck on how to call the value through the associations. Basically, this is what I want:

```
chatroom.current_user.connect.value
```

I keep experimenting in the rails console, but I believe I'm not getting the associations right. I think it can work if `Connect` can have the same association pattern to `User` and `Chatroom` as `Message` does. I tried to do that but RoR seems to not like multiple `has_many through` associations.

Is this something that can be done?